# How do you ignore the fleet menu if it is actually visible in the website when reading from a text.txt file?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

Ok I have created a txt file for my automated c# scripts.  There are only four rows, 1st column is role, 2nd column is email, 3rd column is fleet, 4th column is users.  The first row differs from the rest because the 3rd column has no data so in the text file it reads “”.  When it looks for it in the menu obviously it cannot find it.  Because its not there, the test script just hangs and produces an error unable to locate element and the script fails.  So my question is, is there something I can put in the txt file or something I could put in the code to ignore and carry on:

```
public void AddSingleUser(string email, string role, string [] fleets)
        {
            _regRep.btnAddUser.Click();
            objCommon.EnterText(_regRep.firstNameAdd, userName);
            objCommon.EnterText(_regRep.lastNameAdd, "Smithy");
            objCommon.EnterText(_regRep.userEmailAdd, email);
            objCommon.EnterText(_regRep.userTelephoneAdd, "12345678901");
            objCommon.Exists(_regRep.userRoleManager(role), 10);
            objCommon.ScrollInToViewAndClick(_regRep.userRoleManager(role));

            foreach (string fleet in fleets)
            {
                objCommon.Exists(_regRep.chooseFleet(fleet), 5);
                objCommon.ScrollInToViewAndClick(_regRep.chooseFleet(fleet));
            }
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
            objCommon.ScrollInToViewAndClick(_regRep.btnSaveUser);

            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));
            wait.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.XPath("//div[text() = 'User created.']")));
        }
```

The text file is, please note ,, for empty fleet:

```
Administrator,testadmin@hotmail.com,,fleetmanager@hotmail.com-driver01@hotmail.com-driver06@hotmail.com
Manager,fleetmanager@hotmail.com,Foody Fleet-Fleetingly Employed,fleetmanager01@hotmail.com-driver02@hotmail.com-fleetmanager02@hotmail.com-driver07@hotmail.com
Manager,fleetmanager01@hotmail.com,Foody Fleet-Fleetingly Employed,fleetmanager01@hotmail.com-driver02@hotmail.com-fleetmanager02@hotmail.com-driver07@hotmail.com
Manager,fleetmanager02@hotmail.com,Foody Fleet-Fleetingly Employed,fleetmanager01@hotmail.com-driver02@hotmail.com-fleetmanager02@hotmail.com-driver07@hotmail.com
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to add is a check if `fleet` is `""` (empty string). If so, skip it and move on. I've added the `if` statement into your existing code below.

```
public void AddSingleUser(string email, string role, string [] fleets)
{
    _regRep.btnAddUser.Click();
    objCommon.EnterText(_regRep.firstNameAdd, userName);
    objCommon.EnterText(_regRep.lastNameAdd, "Smithy");
    objCommon.EnterText(_regRep.userEmailAdd, email);
    objCommon.EnterText(_regRep.userTelephoneAdd, "12345678901");
    objCommon.Exists(_regRep.userRoleManager(role), 10);
    objCommon.ScrollInToViewAndClick(_regRep.userRoleManager(role));

    foreach (string fleet in fleets)
    {
        if (fleet != "")
        {
            objCommon.Exists(_regRep.chooseFleet(fleet), 5);
            objCommon.ScrollInToViewAndClick(_regRep.chooseFleet(fleet));
        }
    }
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
    objCommon.ScrollInToViewAndClick(_regRep.btnSaveUser);

    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));
    wait.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.XPath("//div[text() = 'User created.']")));
}
```